# Ubuntu 20.04 black screen with amdgpu pro driver

Tags: drivers, 20.04, gpu, amdgpu, amdgpu-pro

So I have installed ubuntu in a server with intel xeon and six amd firepro S9150, well the first time a I tried install amdgpu-pro-20.45-1225310 opencl, I have downloaded from official amd site and trough terminal unpacked and installed but I got the following message

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms

I resolve installing ubuntu kernel version linux-image-5.4.0.54 and purge amd drives, and uninstall de current version linux-image-5.8.0-53-generic, following the next post:

https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/can-t-install-amdgpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-kernel-5-8-0/td-p/443498

I install the amdgpu pro driver again and the installation complete successfully after I rebooted the computer but I got a black screen with a blinking white stripe in the left upper corner.

I started ubuntu in safe mode and in the load log after the logo boot show me the following message:

[drm:amdgpu_init [amdgpu]] ERROR VGACON disables amdgpu kernel modesettings.

I tried execute kernel from grub with the following parameter to disactivate amdgpu drives

amdgpu.dc=0

but it didn't work and I got a black screen with a blinking white stripe in the left upper corner

NOTE: I can access to safe mode

Does anyone has expirience of installing multiples firepro S9150 with the last driver on Ubuntu 20.04 (linux-image-5.4.0.54)?

Any thoughts will be greatly appreciated